# How to include a xubuntu 13.04 in desktop environment, in wubi

Tags: wubi, xubuntu

How to include a **xubuntu 13.04** in desktop environment, in wubi 
i have downloaded xubuntu but there seemed to be no wubi i also downladed other version **(13.04 => ubuntu, lubuntu )** that include a wubi and when i install using wubi it **works prefect**.

I simply extract **xubuntu 13.04 image** and copied wubi from **ubuntu iso package**, but when i open there is **no xubuntu option** in **Desktop Environment**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu hasn't been available with Wubi since release 12.10. The lead Xubuntu developer, Pasi Lallinaho, requested that it be removed ([reference](http://ubuntu.5.x6.nabble.com/WUBI-tp5020237p5020238.html)):

> There has been discussion about this on the mailing list and on
>   #xubuntu-devel before, but the short answer is that there wasn't enough testers and it was only more workload for the team to support
>   that.

It's still available on the [12.04 Wubi](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/)

There is a way to trick Wubi into installing Xubuntu, if you don't mind a bit of work. This is not recommended, but I did it and wrote up the Howto here: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2012/10/tricking-wubi-installing-xubuntu.html